# JavaFX program toggles full-screen when enter key is pressed inside of a TextField

Tags: java, javafx, fullscreen, textfield

I made my program enter full-screen whenever both of the keyboard keys, alt and enter, are pressed at the same time. This mostly works as expected.

The issue is that my program will toggle full-screen mode whenever the enter key is pressed. It doesn't matter if the alt key is pressed.

How can I make it so that the program will not toggle full-screen mode when only the enter key is pressed.

I am using OpenJFX 11.

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCodeCombination;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;


public class Main extends Application {
   final KeyCombination FullScreenKeyCombo = 
         new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.ENTER, KeyCombination.ALT_ANY);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
            GridPane grid = new GridPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 1600, 900);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();

         // create TextField and add to GridPane
         TextField textField = new TextField();
         grid.add(textField, 0, 0);

         // toggle full-screen when alt + enter is pressed
         scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {

            if(FullScreenKeyCombo.match(event)) {

               stage.setFullScreen(!stage.isFullScreen());

            }
         });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer, just a nit: the whole internal `if` can be replaced with `stage.setFullScreen(!stage.isFullScreen());`.

Comment: Thanks, I will edit my post to add this.

Comment: ALT_ANY means “I don’t care if the Alt key is pressed or not.”  You want `ALT_DOWN`.

Comment: @VGR That fixed my problem! If you want to post an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: ^^ [Indeed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCombination.html#ALT_ANY); please make it an answer so it could be accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.ENTER, KeyCombination.ALT_ANY);
```

ALT_ANY means “I don’t care if the Alt key is pressed or not.”

Use [ALT_DOWN](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/KeyCombination.html#ALT_DOWN) instead:

```
new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.ENTER, KeyCombination.ALT_DOWN);
```

Comment: Thanks again. I should've checked that, but I figured there wouldn't be a point since I didn't know why anyone have to specifically say, "I don't care if _X_ key is pressed or not".